# Nothing returned in getJson but response in Chrome window

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I am using this code:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }, "json");
```

Now, nothing gets logged in the console but i can see the response in the network tab of Chrome. Is there any reason for this? Is the callback wrong?

Comment: Are you sure any data is returned?

Comment: Well i can see it in the network tab, i'd like it as a json object thought

Comment: I had the same issue, which I solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11886993/111884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `, "json"` at the end. Otherwise, `"json"` would be the callback function.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
});
```

Instead of `getJSON` you could use

```
$.get(url, function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
}, "json");
```