# $.getJSON() is not working with chrome,Why?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This code works fine in FF and safari,Not in Chrome why?

```
$.getJSON('s.json', function(data) {
    var items = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
    });

    $('<ul/>', {
        'class' : 'my-new-list',
        html : items.join('')
    }).appendTo('body');
});
```

Comment: Can you define 'not in chrome, why?' Do you get any errors? exceptions?

Comment: Can you setup a demo we can investigate?

Comment: Can you say what is your jQuery version, too?

Comment: Are you opening the file as local file:// or remote as http:// ?

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem, and the issue was that my json was not valid (it had hidden tab characters in it). Chrome seems to be more strict than the other browsers.

Check the response with a `.error` function eg,

```
$.getJSON('s.json', function(data) {
  //...
})
.error(function(data) {
  console.log("Error!");
});
```

You could also try validating the output with something like http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

This approach may still not work but will progressively append elements as they are created thus giving you a better chance of debugging.

```
var $ul = $('<ul></ul>').appendTo('body').addClass('my-new-list');
$.getJSON('s.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $('<li></li>').appendTo($ul).attr('id',key).html(val);
    });
});
```

Inspect the DOM to see how far it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Run the application in webserver. It solves the problem.